# How can I highlight significant correlation in corrplot in R?

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

In corrplot in R, we can highlight insignificant correlation (<0.05) by supplying p-value matrix and using function "insig" and "pch".

But I want highlight only Significant correlation having p-value less than 0.05.

Is there any way to do the opposite?

Best regards

Shriram

Comment: Which `corrplot` are you using? Base does not contain `corrplot`. Do you mean `arm::corrplot`? Also, it would be really nice if you could provide the code that you used to create the first correlation plot, so it's easier to see what you have tried.

Comment: In the `corrplot` package, isn't the base `sig.level` argument 0.05? Could you supply the `p.mat` with `NA` values for those you don't want to plot?

Comment: Hey, @Laterow I am using Corrplot (http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/corrplot/functions/corrplot). I have used following script to generate first correlation plot. corrplot(corr= correlation_matrix, method= "square", is.corr= FALSE, p.mat= p-value_matrix, sig.level= 0.05, pch= 22). @ Tad Dallas I have supplied p.mat and sig.level is default set to 0.05. My question is corrplot by default highlight insignificant correlation having p-vaule more than 0.05. But I want to highlight only significant correlation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the source code of `corrplot`. As far as I understand the code, it is not possible to do the exact opposite to the significant values. The only option that comes really close to what you want is defining `insig = "blank"`. This will cause the non-significant correlations to simply disappear.

The best solution I can think of is to contact the author of the package and ask if this can be implemented: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/index.html

An other option is to tweak the source code of `corrplot` yourself, to adjust it to your needs.

Also, if you haven't yet, check out the vignettes for `corrplot`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html

Edit: Or, specify `insig = blank`, which I think comes pretty close to what you want.. not sure.

Comment: @ Laterow I have tried keeping insig = "blank" and I got my desired output. Thank You so much.

Answer (score 0):

In the corrplot package you can do so by setting the argument `insig = label_sig`.
Doing so will mark all significant values using asterisks, as per the settings of `pch`. You can further personalise how this looks by adjusting the arguments which control `pch`. Use the arguments `pch.cex` and `pch.col` to adjust size and colour respectively.

For more information use ?corrplot, and have a look at the arguments.